# Changing api compiling version

Tags: android, api

I started to program when I'm using 26 API to compile, but I must use 24 API for my project 
I tried to change it from the Project structure - compile sdk  ,but it highlighting in red this following lines -

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

it probably because of the version of not `completeable` with the `target sdk (24)`
what do i need to replace?

Thanks for Reading!!

Comment: You should *always* be compiling with the latest SDK as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd). That doesn't mean you need to target the latest SDK though.

Comment: But I need to use 24 API installed devices

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` is completely separate from `compileSdkVersion`. Read the blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `complieSDKVersion` to `24` and library version to `23.+` then you may have to change the property `android:roundIcon` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to `android:icon`(if `android:icon` property already exist just delete `android:roundIcon` property)

Reason: `android:roundIcon` property was introduced in `API 25` since we need to use  `API 24` for this project, this line will introduce error while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Change this -:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

To-:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Comment: Its not the solution dear. He is asking that by setting compile sdk version 26, want to use 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'.

Comment: and that line? -implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Error:(23) attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.
Error:(23) error: attribute 'android:roundIcon' not found.